# Any finite union of rectangles can be expressed as finite disjoint union of rectangles

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let's call a subset $A\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ a $n-$dimensional rectangle if for some real $a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}$ and $b_{1},b_{2},\dots,b_{n}$:
$$(a_{1},b_{1})\times(a_{2},b_{2})\times\dots\times(a_{n},b_{n}) \subset A \subset [a_{1},b_{1}]\times[a_{2},b_{2}]\times\dots\times[a_{n},b_{n}]$$
I want to prove that any set that is a finite union of $n-$rectangles can be expressed as disjoint finite union of $n-$rectangles $(*)$. But I managed to do it only for the case of $n=1$. My idea was to find this expression as the finite union with the smallest number of intervals($1-$rectangles). I defined an equivalence relation on finite union of intervals $A$ as:
$$x\sim y \Longleftrightarrow [\min(x,y),\max(x,y)]\subset A$$
After that I proved that this is indeed an equivalence relation, and then showed that the equivalence classes are indeed $1-$rectangles(intervals) and that there are only finitely many of such equivalence classes. Now the union of equivalence classes is $A$, so this proves $(*)$ for $n=1$. But I don't see any way to generalize this method, because it seems that for bigger dimensions there are many ways of expressing finite union of $n-$rectangles as finite disjoint union with minimal number of $n-$rectangles. Could you give any hint on generalizing my method or on some other method for proving $(*)$ ?

Comment: I think you can do it via refinement, similar to how it is done for Riemann integrals. Imagine in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that you have two overlapping closed rectangles. By adding extra horizontal and vertical lines "within" the two rectangles, you can separate the overlapping rectangles into several smaller closed rectangles that are disjoint except for their boundaries.

Comment: I see how to do it for two rectangles, but how can I do it in general ?

Comment: Tao formalizes the idea of adding extra lines here on page 6: https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf